# Azure Front Door custom domain redirects to the origin host name (App service)

Tags: azure, azure-appservice, azure-front-door

We have an App Service.

In front of it we have an Azure Front Door.

Everything works perfectly with the Front door default domain .z01.azurefd.net.

The problem is when I am adding a custom domain in front door following the steps from the steps from this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/standard-premium/how-to-add-custom-domain.

Once the domain in up, when I test it in the browser it redirects me to the origin host name: .azurewebsites.net. And that with both domains the custom one and the Front Door's default one.

I tried to delete the origin host header from the origin how it is described in this issue: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/288519/azure-frontdoor-exposing-backend-pool-url-when-aut but doesn't work it gives me a 404 error.

What is missing in my configuration?

Comment: Hi, did you also implement step 3 of the given answer on Q&A? and set https:///.auth/login/aad/callback as callback URL for your app in AzureAD?

Comment: Hi, I do not use authentication and authorization in my App service. So no I did not implement this 3rd step.

Comment: Ever got around to find a solution for this @MirceaGHM?